# Node array filtering not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to filter an array as I have a million times in the past but it's not working.

```
locations = city.locations.filter(
   (l) => {
     console.log(l._id);
     console.log(req.query.locationId);
     console.log(l._id === req.query.location);
     return l._id === req.query.location;
   }
)
```

Console output:

```
l1dr2jmg42lb2sgiudi
l1dr2jmg42lb2sgiudi
false
```

The first two `console.log` print identical strings but the third prints false??!?

I checked that `city.locations` is an `Array` and both `l._id` and `req.query.locationId` are a `string`.

Comment: Show your source data, actual results and desired results. Otherwise your question is off-topic.

Comment: Printing the string can hide undesired spaces before or after it. To make sure try `console.log('"' + l._id + '"')`. It is silly, but it happens.

Comment: @hindmost added the console output

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I checked for spaces. None there. Makes no sense!

Comment: Out of interest if you change `===` to `==` in the 3rd `console.log` what do you get?

Comment: @Jamiec Same output with `==`

Comment: Thanks all! I pledge to get off caffeine for a week as punishment for this one!

Comment: Don;t feel bad. We've all done this kind of thing. Usually means too much, or not enough, coffee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log(l._id === req.query.location);`

you are not referring to `req.query.locationId` but to`req.query.location`. Missing `Id`.

Comment: Oh god! Let this SO page be witness of my shame for posterity!

Comment: @Mika perhaps its time for a break, go get some sleep. haha

Comment: Experience says that computers don't fail at string comparison, but humans do.